# Access Django through model extra fields in m2m_changed signal handler

Tags: django, django-models, django-signals

Let's say I have the following Django models, which represents a sorted relationship between a Parent and Child:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    children = models.ManyToManyField("Child", through="ParentChild")

class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class ParentChild(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["parent", "child"], name="uc_parent_child"),
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["parent", "sort_number"], name="uc_parent_child"),
        ]

    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sort_number = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        exising_sort_numbers = self.parent.parentchild_set.values_list(
            "sort_number", flat=True
        )
        if self.sort_number in exising_sort_numbers:
            raise Exception(f"Duplicate sort number: {self.sort_number}")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now if I create the relationships using the through model, I get the exception for a duplicate `sort_number`:

```
ParentChild.objects.create(parent=parent, child=child1, sort_number=0)
ParentChild.objects.create(parent=parent, child=child2, sort_number=0)  # raises Exception
```

However, if I create the relationships using the `.add` method, I don't get the exception:

```
parent.children.add(child1, through_defaults={"sort_number": 0})
parent.children.add(child2, through_defaults={"sort_number": 0})  # does NOT raise Exception
```

I know [using the .add method doesn't call the .save method on the through model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) so I need to use the `m2m_change` signal to run this logic. But I'm not sure how to get the `sort_number` within this signal. Here's the code I have for the signal so far:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Parent.children.through)
def validate_something(sender, instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, **kwargs):
    if action == "pre_add":
        for pk in pk_set:
            child = model.objects.get(pk=pk)
            exising_sort_numbers = instance.parentchild_set.values_list(
                "sort_number", flat=True
            )
            # where's sort_number specified in through_defaults ???
```

Any idea how I can get this value and perform the `"pre_add"` validation or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this constraint - `models.UniqueConstraint(fields=["parent", "sort_number"], name="uc_parent_child")`, which means that you can't have more than one relation with the same `parent` and `sort_number`. There's even an extra check in `ParentChild`'s `save` method to further enforce this. Makes sense to have an exception thrown when you try to create such a relation.

Also, the constraint name needs to be unique. I tried the code and couldn't make migrations as is.

If you do what you are trying to, you'll get that exception again when saving.
Instead of trying to hack around the constraint, you should either change/remove it or adapt your code to work with it - don't try to create instance which will violate it.

As to your specific question,the instance you get in `validate_something` is `Parent` and there's no direct access to the intermediary instance or it's defaults. You also can't query the intermediary instance, because it does not exist yet.

Comment: That's a shame there's no way to get `sort_number` in the signal handler. What if I wanted to perform a validation that I wasn't able to enforce at the db level. Like the `sort_number` can't be greater than `10`?

Comment: ^ This might not be the best example because there's hacky ways to do this at the Django model level. Better example is to enforce the sort number must be one larger than the max of the existing sort numbers (e.g. `exising_sort_numbers = [0, 1, 2]` then the `sort_number` MUST be `3`)

Answer (score 0):

For any googlers that might be looking for a way to handle through model fields, you can't get it in `pre_add` as @4140tm said, since the record doesn't exist yet. But you can work around it on `post_add` with some effort:

```py
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Parent.children.through)
def validate_something(sender, instance, action, reverse, model, pk_set, **kwargs):
    # notice this is not 'pre_add':
    if action == "post_add":

        # just for clarity:
        parent = instance
        child_model = model
        through_model = sender

        # > OP: where's sort_number specified in through_defaults ???
        # here it is:
        existing_sort_numbers = [pc.sort_number \
            for pc in through_model.objects.filter(parent=parent.id) \
            if pc.child not in pk_set]

        # now just work around (rollback, raise exception, etc):
        for pk in pk_set:
            added_child = child_model.objects.get(id=pk)
            # goes on dirty work...
```